# How to grantUriPermissions() on referred files for ACTION_VIEW?

Tags: android, html, webview, viewer

I have a file manager that allows to pick a file and launch default ACTION_VIEW. For this, I construct the intent like this:

```
    Intent deflt = new Intent();
    deflt.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    deflt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    deflt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    deflt.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
    startActivity(deflt);
```

In particular, when I click in a `.html` file the user can open it with a browser. This is handy for me since I have my whole Home Page saved locally.

Yet, when I select a browser, the actual html file is opened, but with its content stripped: no images, no CSS, only the 'crude' html. Debugging I see tons of `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial`:

```
myPackage E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider 
     uri content://myPackage.provider/external_files/fotoshp/images/pontal-do-atalaia.png
     from pid=9645, uid=10247 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

This makes sense: my intent gives access to the html file, but not to the files referred by it.

Is there a way to allow the browser to see the complete HTML page, with its contents, without doing heavy code reading the `html` and giving permission for each file referred in the `html`? Of course I could open the `html` launching a specific action, launching a web server, or something like that, but I am asking for an "easy" hack.

Comment: Please show an example value of uri.toString(). Which Android version on used device?

Comment: did you created uri using file provider?

Comment: @blackapps I am running my app in Android 11. `Uri.toString()` example: `content://com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.provider/external_files/fotoshp/index.html`

Comment: @SaurabhDhage Yes, like this: `uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, auth + ".provider", file);` Maybe I can do something with the `auth`?

Comment: Im amazed that the browser will change `content://com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.provider/external_files/fotoshp/index.html` to `content://myPackage.provider/external_files/fotoshp/images/pontal-do-atalaia.png`. Is that Chrome browser on an Android device? Content schemes usually dont work that way. Only file schemes. Great browser. And FileProvider refuses. Where do you see those logs?

Comment: `deflt.setDataAndType(uri, mime);` We cannot see which mime type you set.

Comment: Sorry. When I wrote `content://myPackage.provider...` I didn't thought you would ask for the actual uri. Both are the same: `com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.provider`. I see the logs in Android Studio.

Comment: mime = text/html